# Cohomology and 1-forms with compact support

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I'm, having troubles with the following

Let $U$ be a bounded open set in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ such that $\mathbb{R}^{2}\setminus U$ has $n+1$ connected components. Prove that $\dim(H_c^{1}(U))=n$.

I know that every closed $1$-form in $U$ is just the restriction of a $1$-form defined in all of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ and which is equal to $0$ in $\mathbb{R}^{2}\setminus U$.  Therefore each closed $1$-form $\omega$ in $U$ is $\omega=df$, where $f$ has compact support. One can conclude that $f$ is $0$ outside a sufficiently large ball $B$ and constant in n disjoint closed connected "components" inside  $B$. Any suggestions for a next step or a completely new approach?

Thanks

Comment: Since $U$ is bounded, it's complement $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus U$ has one unbounded component (and $n$ bounded ones).

Comment: For each bounded (and hence compact) component, can you find a closed $1$-form that is *not* exact?  Can you see why any closed, *compactly supported* $1$-form on the unbounded component is exact?

Comment: As for the second question I think the same argument of defining the form to be 0 outside the unbounded part will apply, for then it woluld be a closed form defined in all of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, a simply connected set, so it is exact. For the first question, I don't know, I think a concrete space should be picked to build an example.